# CQL_FILTER that joins two feature types in WFS

Tags: geoserver, wfs, cql-filter, getfeature

I want to join two feature types in my WFS in a union. How can I achieve this using CQL? E.g.

```
http://localhost:8080/example/ows?
service=WFS&
version=2.0.0&
request=GetFeature&
srsName=epsg:4283&
typeNames=type1,type2&
```

This returns an error:

> Join query must specify a filter

I'm trying to append a cql_filter parameter, but the ones I try don't work.

What filter can I use to grab both types, in any format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did I understood you right, that you basically want to request two layers in one Request? If so then just use "typeName" instead of "typeNames". 
See this request of two layers at the same time ( bvv:gmd_ex and bvv:lkr_ex ):

http://geoserv.weichand.de:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=bvv:gmd_ex,bvv:lkr_ex&srsName=EPSG:31468&bbox=4450407.80325,5324432.56981,4481624.47895,5346224.56688,EPSG:31468

just tested the the query again on a newer version of Geoserver (2.6.1, with manually **installed querylayer module** ) and this works there,too:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=topp:tasmania_state_boundaries,topp:tasmania_water_bodies

this works also with filter:

[http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=topp:tasmania_state_boundaries,topp:tasmania_water_bodies&CQL_FILTER=INTERSECTS(the_geom,collectGeometries(queryCollection('topp:tasmania_water_bodies', 'the_geom', 'INCLUDE')))](http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=topp:tasmania_state_boundaries,topp:tasmania_water_bodies&CQL_FILTER=INTERSECTS(the_geom,collectGeometries(queryCollection('topp:tasmania_water_bodies',%20'the_geom',%20'INCLUDE'))))

Loading the saved WFS-Response afterwards into QGIS:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your query seems to work but it must be a bug in GeoServer. In WFS 2.0 "typeName" has really changed to "typeNames". Michael's query should work, your query should fail because of unknown keyword. If we accept that GeoServer is right in being lenient with "typeName" it should still work correctly with "typeNames".

Comment: Warning: This example is using GeoServer 2.2. WFS 2.0 joins have been improved since then.

Comment: I agree that typenames would be correct but at my site only typename is working...So perhaps some sort of quick and dirty but it works ;-)