# Trying to perform A WFS CQL_FILTER for multiple TYPENAMES with different GEOM name identifiers

Tags: wfs, cql-filter, getfeature, cql

Using a WFS service `https://geo.onroerenderfgoed.be/geoserver/wfs` I want to retrieve the features with a `CQL INTERSECT` query.

I need to get results from 2 `TYPENAME`:
`vioe_geoportaal:vast_htp,vioe_geoportaal:vast_dibe_relict`

The problem is that the `CQL query` interacts with the geomtry object. In these 2 typenames they are defined different `geom` and `geometry`.

**Request 1**

Where the object is called `geom` is succesful according :

```
https://geo.onroerenderfgoed.be/geoserver/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&CRS=EPSG:31370&OUTPUTFORMAT=application/json&TYPENAME=vioe_geoportaal:vast_htp&CQL_FILTER=INTERSECTS(geom, POLYGON((123664.03100000322 210489.5150000006,123705.24599999934 210489.5150000006,123705.24599999934 210587.86800000072,123664.03100000322 210587.86800000072,123664.03100000322 210489.5150000006)))
```

**Request 2**

Where the object is called `geometry` is succesful according :

```
https://geo.onroerenderfgoed.be/geoserver/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&CRS=EPSG:31370&OUTPUTFORMAT=application/json&TYPENAME=vioe_geoportaal:vast_dibe_relict&CQL_FILTER=INTERSECTS(geometry, POLYGON((123664.03100000322 210489.5150000006,123705.24599999934 210489.5150000006,123705.24599999934 210587.86800000072,123664.03100000322 210587.86800000072,123664.03100000322 210489.5150000006)))
```

**Now I want 1 request to encapsulate the 2 requests above.**

I've tried concatenating them - but as a logical result of the difference in the name `geom` vs `geometry`

```
https://geo.onroerenderfgoed.be/geoserver/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&CRS=EPSG:31370&OUTPUTFORMAT=application/json&TYPENAME=vioe_geoportaal:vast_htp,vioe_geoportaal:vast_dibe_relict&CQL_FILTER=INTERSECTS(geometry, POLYGON((123664.03100000322 210489.5150000006,123705.24599999934 210489.5150000006,123705.24599999934 210587.86800000072,123664.03100000322 210587.86800000072,123664.03100000322 210489.5150000006)))
```

But raises a logical error :

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows https://geo.onroerenderfgoed.be:443/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
    <ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue">
        <ows:ExceptionText>Illegal property name: geometry</ows:ExceptionText>
    </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

What can I do instead of launching 2 request?

Comment: Perhaps duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132229/cql-filter-that-joins-two-feature-types-in-wfs

Comment: leThanks for your remark. I'm not sure this is really the same. It does not explain any further on how to handle a CQL on the geometry with different names. Unless I'm unaware. Not really seeing a solution to my problem. Thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `CQL_FILTER` can have a `;` as delimiter.
Specifiying a filter for each `TYPENAME`.

Using request :

`https://geo.onroerenderfgoed.be/geoserver/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&CRS=EPSG:31370&OUTPUTFORMAT=application/json&TYPENAME=vioe_geoportaal:vast_htp,vioe_geoportaal:vast_dibe_relict&CQL_FILTER=INTERSECTS(geom, POLYGON((123664.03100000322 210489.5150000006,123705.24599999934 210489.5150000006,123705.24599999934 210587.86800000072,123664.03100000322 210587.86800000072,123664.03100000322 210489.5150000006)));INTERSECTS(geometry, POLYGON((123664.03100000322 210489.5150000006,123705.24599999934 210489.5150000006,123705.24599999934 210587.86800000072,123664.03100000322 210587.86800000072,123664.03100000322 210489.5150000006)))`

I was able to address the different shape names like this.
But it feels messy and long... 
Is there really not any other way in achieving this?